# Azure DevOps - Permitir a los usuarios cargar horas pendientes directamente en el Taskboard

Tags: azure, vsts

Quisiera que los usuarios de un proyecto en Azure DevOps puedan modificar individualmente el apartado de Remaining Work directamente en la vista de Taskboard, sin tener que entrar dentro de la tarea concreta y modificarlo dentro. Yo como creador del proyecto puedo hacerlo, pero el resto de usuarios no (incluso con permisos de administrador de equipo, administrador de proyecto,...), ¿hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Revisas bien si los demás son usuarios **básicos**. Los usuarios tipo **stakeholder** no se puede tener la vista de Taskboard. Con una organización Azure DevOps se puede tener los primeros 5 usuarios **básicos** totalmente gratis

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero tu respuesta parece mas bien un comentario, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) un saludo.